# Changing menu item text color in Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, menuitem, android-actionbar

I'm having all sorts of problems implementing styles in action bar, i've read

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Which forces you to inherit some pretty obscure classes and finally managed to change the title text color. Now I'm wanting to change the text color of a menu item which is always preseant in the action bar. Why one earth when I specifiy a global text color it doesn't apply it to anything in the action bar I don't know... Anyway, does anyone know how to change the text color? I can see you can change the background with "android:selectableItemBackground"  but no how to change the text color.

...I don't like to go against the standard but I really want to throw the acion bar out of the window and just make a nice normal relative layout in a fragment.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think that is possible using the published APIs of android.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, frankly I think the Action Bar implementation is way to over complicated. Why bother re-inventing the wheel? Relative layout it is.

Comment: A little ridiculous that this isn't possible. Seems like a basic requirement. But alas, you're prolly right to just use a relative layout.